# Не правильные Constraint'ы у UILabel

Tags: swift, xcode

Есть программа со следующей структурой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь установить constraints для label, после выставления их в storyboard они должны быть на следующем месте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске программы они становятся в позицию по X: 0, Y: 0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли это, из за того, что я в CollectionViewCell всунул TableView?(получается что у меня горизонтальный CollectionView,  ячейки которого содержат в себе вертикальный TableView). При чем если оставить без constaint'ов, то в программе будет все как на storyboard.

Comment: У вас используется то, что в курсах Стэнфордского университета метко называлось "Magic numbers". Т.е констрейнты заданы только для одного размера девайса. На всех прочих будет отображаться неправильно. Сразу в глаза бросается trailing констрейнт равный 291, такого не должно быть никогда. Напишите, что именно хотите сделать, я не понял из объяснения. Просто сделать label отступ слева?

Comment: Я хотел сделать отступ слева и сверху для label

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте закрепить ширину и высоту для Label и поставить constraint  например только к левой границе и верхней